# Plesk 11 DOMAIN Catch All - Wildcard

Tags: apache, dns, wildcard, plesk, catch-all

im wondering and looking around for a possibility of a wildcard/catch all domain setting. I couldnt find anything online so ...

I basically want every domain that points to my site via an A-Record and which gets requested, to display my htdocs default folder.

At the moment every request for a domain that isnt setup as a webspace gets redirected to the default site. <- Thats not what I want.

Does anybody know a solution for this?

Thanks :)

I have Plesk 11.5.30 with Apache running

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to create wildcard subdomain on your domain ? Please have look at  https://kb.plesk.com/en/2239

Comment: And sub domain's web root should points to web root of domain for which one you want to create wildcard. For example  "/httpdocs".